# Rails 4 : Access to association child model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

Example:

```
class Category
end

class Article
     belongs_to :category
end

class Comment
     belongs_to :article
end

class Votes
     belongs_to :comment
end
```

How i can access votes of a category through association ?
Same as: **`Category.first.votes`**

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to complete your associations: Every `belongs_to` should have a corresponding `has_many`/`has_one`

```
class Category
   has_many :articles
end

class Article
   has_many :comments
   belongs_to :category
end

class Comment
  has_many :votes, class_name: :votes #rails will look for class Vote, so you have to specify that the class name is actually 'votes'
  belongs_to :article
end
```

Then with the appropriate, has_many through association

```
class Category
   has_many :articles
   has_many :comments, through: :articles
   has_many :votes, through: :comments
end
```

Now you should be able to call `Category.first.votes` and get all the votes for the first category